# How to understand oriented intersection number in the non-transversal case? (including in the definition of Euler characteristic)

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology

### Background

I am reading through Guiellman and Pollack's *Differential Topology*. Ultimately I would like to understand the Euler characteristic. On page 116, they define the Euler characteristic of a compact oriented manifold $Y$ as the oriented self-intersection number of the diagonal $\Delta$ in $Y\times Y$. This definition is based on the definition of oriented intersection number of a pair of oriented submanifolds $X\subset Y$, $Z\subset Y$. When $X$ is transversal to $Z$ (and we have dimensional complementarity so that $Y=X\oplus Z$), I understand the concept of the oriented intersection number: At each intersection point of $X,Y$, just concatenate an oriented basis of $X$ with an oriented basis of $Z$ and see if you get an oriented basis of $Y$. If you do, then the local intersection number at that point is positive, otherwise it's negative.  Then add up the local intersection numbers from each point of intersection. (Note: if you are familiar with the intersection number $I(f,Z)$ as defined for a function $f$ mapping into $Y$ instead of $I(X,Z)$ for a submanifold $X$, the latter notion can be derived from the former by setting $f$ to be the inclusion map $X\hookrightarrow Y$.)

### Main Question

Where I am struggling to understand is when $X$ is not transversal to $Y$ (and I think this will basically always be the case when $Z=X$ as in the Euler characteristic definition). I gather that the thing to do is to slightly deform $X$ so it becomes transversal to $Z$ and then look at the intersection number of the deformed version of $X$ with $Z$ as defined above. But we would need to know that the resulting number doesn't depend on how we deform $X$ (within some neighborhood). This is where I am confused.

It may be useful to consider an example where $X=Z$ is the x-axis in $\mathbb{R^2}$ such that the positive direction  (i.e. moving from left to right) is considered positively orientated. It would appear to me that the intersection number we get after deforming $X$ (leaving $Z$ alone) would depend on whether we rotate $X$ clockwise or counterclockwise. If clockwise, I think we would get a positively orientated basis for $\mathbb{R^2}$ (so an intersection number of 1) and if counterclockwise we would get a negatively oriented basis of $\mathbb{R^2}$ (so an intersection number of -1). I think there is some mistake in my understanding here? Note that I am thinking of the tangent space of $X$ as the first element of the basis and of the tangent space of $Z$ as the second element of the basis (of $\mathbb{R^2}$).

Possibly relevant: I have read through the proof that the intersection number (also apparently called degree) is homotopy invariant (from Guilleman and Pollack and from Milnor) and I think I understand this proof (which uses the classication of 1-manifolds) but I don't see how the non-transversal case is accounted for.

As a secondary question, I am also not sure how to define the oriented intersection number when $X$ *is* transveral to $Z$ but their tangent spaces overlap as in $\mathbb{R^3}$. A third question is how to define oriented intersection number when $X$ is not transveral to $Z$ but where their tangent spaces do not overlap as with two perpendicular lines intersecting at a point in $\mathbb{R^3}$.

Note: I have not had the time to properly work through Guilleman and Pollack line-by-line from the beginning. I have skipped over several parts so it is possible that I have missed some important concept that is typically presumed when presenting this material.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to read the earlier parts of  the book. The crucial thing you’re missing is that $X$ must be compact (and $Z$ closed). Indeed, in your example, you can push the $x$-axis up and have no intersections at all.

Comment: Thanks, I think I see what's going on here now. A better example is where = is the equator on the sphere. Then the oriented intersection number is zero no matter how you deform . This leads me to think if the oriented intersection number in the non-transversal case is always zero? To show this we would try to pull $X$ away from $Z$  along the dimension (backwards or forwards?) that is not being covered by the combined tangent spaces--such a dimension exists by non-travsersality. Will have to think about a rigorous proof.

Comment: No. When $\dim X$ is odd, it will be $0$, but not when it's even. Go back to where your question started. Take the diagonal in $S^2\times S^2$ or take $\Bbb CP^1$ in $\Bbb CP^2$.

Comment: Αfter reading the lefschetz section, I see that $\chi$ is 2 for $S^2\times S^2$ since the map that moves everything south keeping poles fixed is homotopic to identity. I don't understand whether we need to restrict to boundaryless ? E.g. in $X=[0,1]$ I'm confused about the corners of the square. Self-int # of diagonal seems to vary by 1 as we perturb to add new crosses keeping end pts fixed: Adding a new cross of Δ, we also change the direction from which we are approaching one of the corners. The latter change would be a $\pm 2$ which would overcompensate for the $\pm1$ of new cross?

Comment: If $X$ has boundary, intersection number is no longer a homotopy invariant. If you require that no intersection occurs at the boundary and that homotopy fix the boundary, perhaps something works. I’ve never thought about it.